# Why is this getting the same row twice in second loop?

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The code below runs with no apparent errors, but despite I've looked for all possible causes I could think of, I couldn't find the reason why it gets the correct row iterated, marks it as processed ("Sim), and from the 2º iteration on, it gets the new row, but repeats the others already iterated over.

```
function formToData() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = sheet.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var targetSheet = sheet.getSheetByName("Cadastro de Cliente");
  var StartRow = 2;
  var RowRange = ss.getLastRow() - StartRow + 1;
  var WholeRange = ss.getRange(StartRow, 1, RowRange, 30);
  var AllValues = WholeRange.getValues();
  var message = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < AllValues.length; i++) {
    var currentRow = AllValues[i];
    //if row has been sent, then continue to next iteration
    if (currentRow[0] != "" && currentRow[29] != "Sim") {
      //set the row to look at
      var setRow = parseInt(i) + StartRow;

      var data = currentRow[0];
      var dataFormatted = Utilities.formatDate(data, SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy', às 'HH:mm") + "hs";

      //set HTML template for information
      message +=
        "<p><b>Data: </b>" + dataFormatted + "</p>" +
        "<p><b>Unidade: </b>" + currentRow[1] + "</p>"

      //mark row as "sent"
      ss.getRange(setRow, 30).setValue("Sim");

      var values = targetSheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();
      var maxIndex = values.reduce(function (maxIndex, row, index) {
        return row[0] === "" ? maxIndex : index;
      }, 0);
      targetSheet.getRange(maxIndex + 2, 1, 1, 30)
        .setNumberFormat("@")
        .setValues([currentRow]);

      var sendTo = "email";
      var subject = "Cadastro de cliente novo";
      if (message) {
        MailApp.sendEmail({
          to: sendTo,
          subject: subject,
          name: "Comercial - Emape",
          htmlBody: message,
        });
      }
    }
  }//For loop closes
}
```

I'd appreaciate if you could help me find the flaw.

Comment: Until someone takes the time and runs this code on his example dataset. If you have some time to check the code yourself, I would advice you to `console.log` variables to monitor the iteration steps in the for loop. In this way you can see where your code fails and locate the error. For example, `console.log(currentRow)`. If you think you are iterating again over the same rows, it means that the value of this variable does not change properly. You can spot for which `i` itdoes that and see if your sheet has an issue there. Printing values is the best way to debug a code in any progr. language.

Comment: Hello @Marios! I've done that and currentRow logged is correct. I think there might an error between the mesaqge being composed and setting the value ("Sim")... I've even tried Spreadsheet.flush(), but it didn't solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to replicate this behavior, however, on a static sheet the script performs as expected:

1. Set unmarked rows in column 30 as 'Sim'.
2. Copy these rows to a separate sheet starting from the first empty row (or whichever row that Column A is empty).

Given the names of the functions and the sheets, this may be a Sheet generated by a Google Form. These sheets are dynamic, and there is a possibility that the contents may change while your script is running, especially if users are allowed to edit responses.

As a workaround, I suggest to lock the form before running the script:

[image]

Also, check the contents of the sheet and form for any possibility that the "Sim" mark might be overwritten by new or edited form data, maybe the sheet is inserting 30 columns instead of 29 or less.